# Additional Repositories List

Tags: linux

Bom dia !
Sou iniciante em linux e em programação, e tive um problema. 
Uso o linux mint 19 
Ao instalar bibliotecas no meu computador, eu instalei dois repositórios iguais, e agora nao consigo arrumar. 
Ao tentar atualizar os pacotes, retorna o seguinte erro "imenso" 

 

*W: Target Packages (stable/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:4
W: Target Packages (stable/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:4
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-pt_BR) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:4
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-pt) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:4
W: Target Translations (stable/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (stable/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:4
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:4
W: Target CNF (stable/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:4*


Fui até o repositorio indicado, e ao ler o arquivo additional-repositories.list, eu identifiquei 2 linhas iguais 
 
 *deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu    tara    stable
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu    tara    stable
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic*                                                 

Não consigo apagar a linha duplicada, porque esse arquivo é readonly. Como eu consigo resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa ser root para editar `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list`.
Dá uma lida aqui para entender mais sobre como [editar arquivos como root](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-edit-as-root.html.pt_BR).
E [aqui](https://www.alura.com.br/artigos/entendendo-as-permissoes-no-linux) pra entender sobre permissões de arquivos.

Se você usa o `vim`:

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list
```